# Expected value of joint normal PDF

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> The joint pdf of a bivariate random variable (X,Y) is given by
>   $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{3}(x^2-xy+y^2+x-2y+1)}$$
>   Find the means of $X$ and $Y$.

To my understanding, the formula for this is

$$ E(X)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x f(x,y)dxdy $$

and

$$ E(Y)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} y f(x,y)dxdy $$

However, I don't see a way of computing either of these integrals for this function.  Am I missing something?

**Update:**

So essentially if I'm comparing the exponents to that of the bivariate normal distribution, then I'm comparing this:

$$-\frac{1}{3}(x^2-xy+y^2+x-2y+1)=-\frac{(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})^2-2p(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})+(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})^2}       {2(1-p)^2}$$

Would it be right to set $$x=\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}$$ and $$y=\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}$$

so then $$-2y+x-xy+1=-2p(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})=-2p\frac{xy-x\mu_2-y\mu_1+\mu_1\mu_2}{\sigma_1\sigma_2}$$

Then by comparing $-2y=-y\mu_1$.  So $\mu_1=2$

Comment: A shortcut: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac1{2\sqrt{3}\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{3}(x^2-x(y-1)+(y-1)^2)}$$ is a symmetric function of $$(x,y-1)=(x-\color{red}{0},y-\color{blue}{1})$$ hence the gaussian vector $(X,Y)$ is centered at $$(E(X),E(Y))=(\color{red}{0},\color{blue}{1})$$

Comment: Thank you!  Though I'm not sure I completely understand as I'm not familiar with Gaussian vectors.  Is there a place where I could read up more on this?  And could this be applied to find variances of $X$ and $Y$ as well?

Comment: For the variances, identifying the distribution is necessary. Reference on gaussian vectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: This is a bivariate normal distribution; to find the mean and variance, try to manipulate the exponent into what appears for a bivariate normal variable.